# Angular material html looks funny, how to render this correct

Tags: angular, visual-studio, angular-material

I learn Angular and now the Component html look funny. This should be a Angual material but I missed something in the code I think!

This is my search-books.component.html

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header><mat-card-title>New Contact</mat-card-title></mat-card-header>
  <form [formGroup]="newContact" class="form-container">

    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
      <mat-error *ngIf="formControlName.hasError('required')">
        Name is <strong>required</strong>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Type" formControlName="type">
        <mat-option [value]="1">
          Work
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="2">
          Cellphone
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="3">
          Home
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="formControlName.hasError('required')">
        Type is <strong>required</strong>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="tel" matInput placeholder="Number" formControlName="number">
      <mat-error *ngIf="formControlName.hasError('required')">
        Number is <strong>required</strong>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button mat-raised-button class="submitForm" (click)="addContact()">Save</button>
  </form>
</mat-card>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="goBack()" class="backButton" title="Go Back"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>Back</button>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: can you create a stackblitz

Comment: Please create a stackblitz example, and make sure you have everything that is needed for angular material to work. Follow this guide `https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems, you might have missed the export of your material module or you haven't added any default theme of material in the application

To create simple material app, please use below commands.

```
ng add @angular/material

 ng generate @angular/material:materialNav --name myNav
 ng generate @angular/material:materialDashboard --name myDashboard
 ng generate @angular/material:materialTable -- name myTable
```

E.g. if you use the first command to generate a new myNav component you should be able to see the following output on the command line:

```
CREATE src/app/my-nav/my-nav.component.css (110 bytes)
CREATE src/app/my-nav/my-nav.component.html (945 bytes)
CREATE src/app/my-nav/my-nav.component.spec.ts (605 bytes)
CREATE src/app/my-nav/my-nav.component.ts (481 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (795 bytes)
```

To make it visible to the user delete the default content of file app.component.html and just insert the following element:

```
 <my-nav></my-nav>
```

[Please follow this blog](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-material-and-angular-6-material-design-for-angular-6b1a3ee476f0)

Comment: I missed @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";